# Why two same codes are giving different outputs yet the only difference between them is different variables names and writing style.

Tags: c++

These two programs made to calculate prime numbers in the user giving range.
**This is not giving correct output** I don't know why? why just variables name and writing style are making different outputs? Plz let me know if anybody can guide me .

```
  #include<iostream>
    using namespace std;
    int main()
    {
        int upper_limit=0;
        int lower_limit=0;
        int num=0;
        int flag=0;
        cout<<"Enter lower limit"<<endl;
        cin>>lower_limit;
        cout<<"Enter upeer limit"<<endl;
        cin>>upper_limit;
            for (int i=lower_limit;i<=upper_limit;i++)
            {
                for (int j=2;j<=i/2;j++)
                {
                    if (i%j==0)
                    {
                        flag++;
                    }
                    if ((flag==0)&&(i!=1))
                    {
                        num++;
                        cout<<"prime numbers are"<<i<<endl;
                        flag=0;
                    }
                    flag=0;
                }
            }
            cout<<"Total prime num are"<<num<<endl;
        return 0;
    }
```

**This is giving correct output** but why , both codes are same.

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
    int startNum,endNum;
    int found=0,count=0;
    cout<<"Enter Number START of Range:  ";
    cin>>startNum;
    cout<<"Enter Number END of Range:  ";
    cin>>endNum;
    for(int i=startNum;i<=endNum;i++)
       {
           for(int j=2;j<=i/2;j++)
               {
               if(i%j==0)
                  count++;
               }
               if(count==0&&i!=1)
               { found++;
                 cout<<"Prime Number -> "<<i<<endl;
                 count=0;
               }
               count=0;
       }

 cout<<"Total Prime Number Between Range "<<startNum<<" to"<<endNum<<" = "<<found<<endl;
 return 0;
}
```

Comment: The first one has an extra set of braces which changes the program flow

Comment: Start with the second-last line, ie. the ouput. There's more difference than var names and code style.

Comment: In the correct code, the seconf `if` is outside the second loop.

Comment: This is why consistent indentation style is a must have.  You would have spotted the difference easily then.  See the difference [here](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/c4a6dedd698ab728)

Comment: If you have a decent editor, use `Ctrl-A` and its "indent" command.

Comment: OMG, I haven't noticed it . You are a life saver. Thank u soo much. Thanks a lot. I am wondering I spend 2 hours looking for difference between these two codes but didn't find any1. But you find in just 2 minutes. genious. Again thanks.

Comment: Hopefully this is a good lesson about why that indentation style is terrible!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is in the braces.
First program:

```
for (int i=lower_limit;i<=upper_limit;i++)
{
    for (int j=2;j<=i/2;j++)
    { <------------------------------- 
        if (i%j==0)
        {
            flag++;
        }
        if ((flag==0)&&(i!=1))
        {
            num++;
            cout<<"prime numbers are"<<i<<endl;
            flag=0;
        }
        flag=0;
    } <------------------------------- 
}
```

Second program:

```
for(int i=startNum;i<=endNum;i++)
{
   for(int j=2;j<=i/2;j++)
   { <------------------------------- 
       if(i%j==0)
          count++;
   } <------------------------------- 
   if(count==0&&i!=1)
   { 
        found++;
        cout<<"Prime Number -> "<<i<<endl;
        count=0;
   }
   count=0;
}
```

This is why it is very important to tabulate correctly the program code.